# date() and gmdate() return different results

Tags: php

I run a simple test comparing output of date() and gmdate() and I'm puzzled with results. I understand the difference between functions, however, the server is set to GMT time so I would expect the result to be identical.

I checked timezone setting and they seem to be fine. I suspect this has something to do with daytime savings.

I am right to expect the output to be the same?

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

echo '<br>Full date '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s T I");
echo '<br>Full date GM '.gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s T I");

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s T I");
$tempDate = $startWeek = time();

$date = new DateTime();
$tempDateU = $date->format('U');

$tempDate = $startWeek = time();
echo '<br>Date: '.date("d/m/y H:i", $tempDate); 
echo '<br>GM Date: '.gmdate("d/m/y H:i", $tempDate);

echo '<br>Date: '.date("d/m/y H:i", $tempDateU); 
echo '<br>GM Date: '.gmdate("d/m/y H:i", $tempDateU);
```

Output:

```
date_default_timezone_set: Europe/London

Full date 2016-04-29 11:35:55 BST 1
Full date GM 2016-04-29 10:35:55 GMT 0
Date: 29/04/16 11:35
GM Date: 29/04/16 10:35
Date: 29/04/16 11:35
GM Date: 29/04/16 10:35
```

Comment: `Europe/London` != `GMT`

Comment: Looks like the server is set to `Europe/London` which *isn't* GMT at the moment but BST (British Summer Time) => GMT+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.*

So you need to set your current timezone to be sure what you are doing:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Or

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Like mentioned before, Europe/London is not the same as GMT/UTC.

Reminder: GMT does not have DST, it is always the same time.
Europe/London has DST. That is why I in gmdate gives 0

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Wasn't aware that GMT is not taking DST into account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, daylight saving is causing this.
Hence the date() says BST 1 and gmdate() says GMT 0.

Not sure why though, will look into it. Possibly as the time zone is London, so it's in BST.